# Gnome Classic: Application switcher popupu and other similar popups unreadable after update to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, gnome-classic

Edit: I must mention that the attached picture is the popup showing the list of open windows when I press alt+tab.  I don't think there is any extension causing this.  I believe this is a gnome-classic bug.  In the attached picture, you can barely see the white "Wikipedia - Mozilla Firefox" on a white background at the bottom.

As the title says, the popups such as application switcher, volume/brightness change popups have gray text/icons on gray background and is barely readable as can be seen in [attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKTTw.jpg).  (Sorry, I could not take a screenshot while the popup was active so had to use camera.)

Of course, I spent several hours trying to find a solution online first but no luck.  I tried changing themes in Gnome Tweaks.  I tried different sessions such as Gnome Classic Wayland and Gnome Classic Xorg.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: many of the original GNOME Shell Extensions are deprecated in GNOME v42. If not already installed, install Extension Manager Manager from Ubuntu Software, open it and use the *Browse* tab to search for extensions you may be interested in.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I installed the extension manager.  What kind of extensions would fix this problem?  Actually, I don't even know which extension allows application/window switching like that.

Comment: start off by using the name as it was in the old arrangement. eg *Application Switcher* now suggests a number of alternatives against which you will see **Install** and avoid those that say **Unsupported** Use the right chevron to get a better description of what it does.

Comment: I cannot find anything related to windows/application switching in existing extensions as well as in the manager.  I forgot to mention that the attached picture is the popup displayed after pressing alt+tab, so I believe it is some default behavior in gnome and not part of any extension.